# Sun T5240 Server ILOM missing /SYS - can't get to boot OS

Tags: boot, sun, sparc

I've acquired a Sun T5240 that's supposed to be in good working order.  I can't get the server to the point of booting/installing operating systems though.

Logging into ILOM via serial (ser mgt port) and web (net mgt port) works (slowly), but there is no /SYS target (or /System) and vistually nothing listed in any pane via the web interface (version info, but that's about it).  The only two top level targets are /HOST and /SP.  I can't get to OpenBoot without /SYS as far as I can tell; neither can I check the actual server hardware (CPU, memory, etc).

I can't log on as default - it asks for the physical presence button to be pressed and released, but neither the front nor back locator button works (have tried quick press, 5 second press, 10 second press, multiple presses) - when hitting return after it always says nothing detected and goes back to login.

I've reset the SP to factory defaults and reset it multiple times, but no change.  There are no faults under /SP/faultmgmt (or show faulty).

I see this on ILOM bootup regarding the tffs kernel module, and ***I suspect this is actually the real problem:***

```
tffs: Looking for H1 DOC at address 0xcd14e000
tffs: No DiskOnChips found
/lib/modules/2.4.22/misc/tffs/tffs_h3.o: init_module: Device or resource busy
Hint: insmod errors can be caused by incorrect module parameters, including 
invalid IO or IRQ parameters.
```

Other ILOM boot logs on the web show the tffs module finding some device there which is then used as part of the filesystem.  Sounds like that's the problem - but not sure what can be done to resolve it...

I also see this on ILOM login as root:

`Timed out waiting for daemons to start
vbsc daemon failed to start
sccd daemon failed to start`

And every now and again:

`"cnsd" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes`

When ILOM starts up, there are lots of I/O looking issues - files cannot be written, opened, etc.  I think this might be SCC related from a quick google around, but I'm no Sun engineer.

Also, there are a few minor things listed in the event log that look inconsequential, but one is critical:

```
1      Mon Feb 19 17:24:40 2018  Internal  Product   critical
       Servicetag failed to get internal product data after 300 seconds
```

Any ideas where to start?  Am I missing something really obvious, or is the machine damaged?

Version info:

- SP firmware 3.0.12.4.zc
- SP firmware build number: 86338
- SP firmware date: Tue Jan 14 17:39:19 PST 2014
- SP filesystem version: 0.1.22

NB: full login transcript:

`ORACLESP-XXxxXXxxXXxx login: root
Password:
Waiting for daemons to initialize...
.............................
...............
INIT: Id "cnsd" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
...............
Timed out waiting for daemons to start
vbsc daemon failed to start
sccd daemon failed to start`

`Oracle(R) Integrated Lights Out Manager`

`Version 3.0.12.4.zc r86338`

`Copyright (c) 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.`

`Warning: password is set to factory default.`

`->`

Comment: Bit more info if it helps: during ILOM boot, it looks like the tffs driver isn't finding something it needs - it reports the kernel module failed to load and no diskonchips found...

Comment: Sounds like the server you acquired is not in the "good working order" you were told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that system firmware is corrupted. Try to update it via

```
-> load -source tftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/filename.pkg
```